# Substvars Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: debian, ubuntu, packaging

**Edit**:
Updated full *debian/rules* and *debian/control* file

I am working on a web project which need to build two debian packages for different deployment server. The main differences is the limitation of depends in *debian/control* file. So I wrote below:

```
Source: web-app
Section: non-free/web
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Me
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 4.0.0), build-essential
Standards-Version: 3.8.0
Homepage: http://abc.com

Package: web-app
Architecture: all
Depends: apache2, libapache2-mod-rpaf, openssl, rsync, imagemagick, mysql-client, ${other-depends}, libjs-cropper, libjs-jquery (>= 1.3.3-1), libjs-prototype, libjs-scriptaculous, libphp-phpmailer (>= 1.73-4), libphp-snoopy, tinymce (>= 3.2.6-0.1)
Description: Short description
  Long description here.
```

And the *debian/rules* file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS=-X .svn

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk

# Add here any variable or target overrides you need.

# platform related package dependencies
XENIAL_LIBS = php7.0, php7.0-opcache, php-apcu, php7.0-mysql, php7.0-gd
PRE_XENIAL_LIBS = apache2-mpm-prefork, apache2-prefork-dev, php5.5, php-apc,      php-gettext, php5-mysql, php5-gd

ifeq ($(shell lsb_release -cd | awk '/^Codename:/ { print $2}'), xenial)
    PLATFORM_LIBS := $(XENIAL_LIBS)
else
    PLATFORM_LIBS := $(PRE_XENIAL_LIBS)
endif

override_dh_gencontrol:
    dh_gencontrol -- -Vother-depends="$(PLATFORM_LIBS)"

configure: configure-stamp
configure-stamp:
    touch configure-stamp

build: build-stamp
build-stamp: configure-stamp
    dh_testdir
    dpkg-parsechangelog | awk '$$0 ~ /^Version:/ {print $$2}' > version.txt
    touch build-stamp
```

One of the deployment target is Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), it should replace the **other-depends** with **PRE_XENIAL_LIBS**. But I got the final control file for the server like this:

```
Depends: apache2, openssl, rsync, imagemagick, php, php-opcache, php-apcu, mysql-client, php-gettext, php-mysql, php-gd ...
```

What's wrong, and how to fix it?

**=================Updates=================**

I have modified my **debian/rules** file based on Wouter's answer, but still doesn't get the correct substitution. Then I ran the command

```
dpkg-buildpackage
```

Then found a warning from the output:

```
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Depends field of package web-app: unknown substitution variable ${other-depends}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your syntax is wrong, and will result in a command line like...

```
dh_gencontrol -- -Vdist:Depends=""php7.0, php7.0-opcache, ...""
```

rather than (what you would want):

```
dh_gencontrol -- -Vdist:depends="php7.0, php7.0-opcache, ..."
```

this is because `make` doesn't do quoting, and you quote the data in the variable twice (once in the assignment, once when you use it). Drop one of them.

Second, the reason it's not working is because your debian/rules file (as written) will not invoke `dh_gencontrol` with the extra arguments you want. A `debian/rules` file is a `Makefile`; therefore, it should have make rules etc in it, otherwise they get ignored. Something like this does what's expeted on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@
PKGS := abcd, efgh
override_dh_gencontrol:
        dh_gencontrol -- -Vdist:Depends="$(LIBS)"
```

If that still doesn't do what you're expecting, then a full example (i.e., something you can run `dpkg-buildpackage` on) is absolutely necessary.

**EDIT**: You still have the double quoting. The `XENIAL_LIBS` and `PRE_XENIAL_LIBS` lines have quotes around them. Remove them. Also, you still haven't provided an example that `dpkg-buildpackage` will not complain about (for one thing, the control file is incomplete). It doesn't have to be what you're working on is that contains company secrets, but a minimal example that demonstrates the problem is essential. With what you've provided so far, I can't reproduce your problem.

**EDIT2**: Your full rules file shows you're using CDBS, not debhelper's `dh`. As such, the `override_dh_gencontrol` target isn't being called (that's a `dh`-specific thing). I don't know how CDBS deals with overriding individual debhelper commands (which is why I hadn't replied to this before my holiday, hoping that maybe someone else might tell you what to do), but it's probably something along the lines of another CDBS_FOO_BAR variable that you must set. Luckily, your `debian/rules` file is simple enough that the port from cdbs is rather straightforward. Apply the following patch:

```
--- rules.old   2016-07-12 16:57:05.350385288 +0200
+++ rules       2016-07-12 16:58:54.456536432 +0200
@@ -1,8 +1,7 @@
 #!/usr/bin/make -f

-DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS=-X .svn
-
-include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk
+%:
+       dh $@

 # Add here any variable or target overrides you need.

@@ -16,15 +15,10 @@
     PLATFORM_LIBS := $(PRE_XENIAL_LIBS)
 endif

+override_dh_install:
+       dh_install -X .svn
 override_dh_gencontrol:
        dh_gencontrol -- -Vother-depends="$(PLATFORM_LIBS)"
-
-configure: configure-stamp
-configure-stamp:
-       touch configure-stamp
-
-build: build-stamp
-build-stamp: configure-stamp
-       dh_testdir
+override_dh_auto_build:
        dpkg-parsechangelog | awk '$$0 ~ /^Version:/ {print $$2}' > version.txt
-       touch build-stamp
+       dh_auto_build
```

First, this drops the CDBS include and the CDBS-specific `DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS` variable, which `dh` does not support, and adds the wildcard `Makefile` target that dh requires in its place. It also adds the `override_dh_install` target, which replaces the `DEB_DH_INSTALL_ARGS` variable.

Second, this drops the `configure` and `build` targets, as well as the `configure-stamp` and `build-stamp` ones. `dh` does not use those (and it is, indeed, harmful to retain them).

Finally, we add another override target which does the dpkg-parsechangelog thing to create your version.txt file. Your actual build process is probably something else, but this shows you how to replace it.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, this is really helpful! Unfortunately, still doesn't do the correct substitution. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I don't see any updates?

Comment: Oops! I didn't realized you're still online, so I add comments firstly, then edit the answer. Sorry!

Comment: Well, sortof :-) the app notifies me if there's a message...

Comment: Question updated, :-)